How to transfer large data with IOUserClient AsyncCompletion
I'm trying to make an asynchronous bulk data read using IOUSBHostPipe AsyncIO/CompleteAsyncIO and send the data back to the user-space application using AsyncCompletion.
virtual void AsyncCompletion(OSAction *action, IOReturn status, const IOUserClientAsyncArgumentsArray asyncData, uint32_t asyncDataCount);

My understanding is that the IOUserClientAsyncArgumentsArray asyncData in AsyncCompletion method has a limited size of 128 bytes, and the data I need to send back is over 10k bytes.
Would it be possible to send such large data from the driver to the user-space application using async callback?
Thanks
